# Google Maps Distance Matrix Traffic Assumptions

Tags: google-distancematrix-api

I am trying to figure out exactly how the distance matrix API processes traffic for driving. Currently, I am using the advanced version of the API by specifying a date and time of departure. I use the [gmapsdistance](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmapsdistance/gmapsdistance.pdf) package in R, and specify "None" for the traffic_model (my understanding is this is equivalent to reading in "" to the API).

What is the difference between this, and running the API on the basic version (i.e. not specifying a date and time for departure)? Some results were different when comparing the two options, but I cannot pin down why.

Thank you!